# AWS Lambda /tmp python script import module error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to run a python script that is present in AWS Lambda /tmp directory. The scripts require some extra dependencies like boto3 etc to run the file. When AWS Lambda runs the file it gives out the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'boto3'
```

However when i run this file directly as a lambda function then it runs easily whithout any import errors.

The Lambda Code that is trying to execute the code present in /tmp directory :

```
import json
import os
import urllib.parse
import boto3
s3 = boto3.client('s3')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    records = [x for x in event.get('Records', []) if x.get('eventName') == 'ObjectCreated:Put']
    sorted_events = sorted(records, key=lambda e: e.get('eventTime'))
    latest_event = sorted_events[-1] if sorted_events else {}
    info = latest_event.get('s3', {})
    file_key = info.get('object', {}).get('key')
    bucket_name = info.get('bucket', {}).get('name')
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    BUCKET_NAME = bucket_name
    keys = [file_key]
    for KEY in keys:
        local_file_name = '/tmp/'+KEY
        s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME).download_file(KEY, local_file_name)
        print("Running Incoming File !! ")
        os.system('python ' + local_file_name)
```

The /tmp code that is trying to get some data from S3 using boto3 :

```
import sys
import boto3
import json


def main():
    session = boto3.Session(
                aws_access_key_id='##',
                aws_secret_access_key='##',
                region_name='##')
                
    s3 = session.resource('s3')

    # get a handle on the bucket that holds your file
    bucket = s3.Bucket('##')

    # get a handle on the object you want (i.e. your file)
    obj = bucket.Object(key='8.json') 

    # get the object
    response = obj.get()

    # read the contents of the file
    lines = response['Body'].read().decode()
    data = json.loads(lines)
    transactions = data['dataset']['fields']
    print(str(len(transactions)))
    return str(len(transactions))

main()
```

So boto3 is imported in both the codes . But its only successful when the lambda code is executing it . However /tmp code cant import boto3 .
What can be the reason and how can i resolve it ?

Comment: Can you upload code that you are trying to execute on /tmp as well as the code which is executing this file from tmp location of lambda?

Comment: @amitd Uploaded the code . Please check.

Comment: Why did you put source code in the `/tmp` folder?

Answer (score 1):

Executing another python process does not copy Lambda's PYTHONPATH by default:

```
os.system('python ' + local_file_name)
```

Rewrite like this:

```
os.system('PYTHONPATH=/var/runtime python ' + local_file_name)
```

In order to find out complete PYTHONPATH the current Lambda version is using, add the following to the first script (one executed by Lambda):

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```